# concatinating even and odd places in a string

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I'm learning basics in coding. Can any one say what went wrong with my code
Prob:Given a string, S, of length  N that is indexed from 0 to N-1  , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char input[100], final[100];

int main()
{
    int num, i, j;
    char even[50], odd[50], space[] = "  ";
    scanf("%d", &num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        int k = 0, p = 0;
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", input);
        for (j = 0; input[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
            {
                even[k] = input[j];
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                odd[p] = input[j];
                p++;
            }
        }
        strcat(final, even);
        strcat(final, space);
        strcat(final, odd);
    }
    printf("%s", final);
}
```

Comment: I gave input as 1
hacks
**My Output**
hcs�  ak

Comment: You haven't terminated your odd and even strings with \0, and haven't initialized your final string, meaning that strcat cannot work.

Comment: Note that your `scanf()`-conversion in `" %[^\n]s"` is incorrect.

Comment: Once termination is fixed, `char even[50]` is one too small.